# Bulid URL from checkbox values (array) Android

Tags: java, android, http, checkbox

My main view has 4 checkboxes and a submit button. I am trying to build a url from the values selected on the checkboxes.  Below is the base of my page I am not sure how to program the collection of the checkbox values and submit to my function that does an http call with the checkbox values in the url query.

Any help would be great.

```
package com.flash_tattoo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;
import com.flash_tattoo.DataCall;

public class flash_tattoo extends Activity {

    private Button get_images;

    private CheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        get_images = (Button)findViewById(R.id.get_images);

            CheckBox[] setOfCheckBoxes = new CheckBox[]
           {
         (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
         (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);        
         (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
         (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
          };
       for(int i = 0; i < setOfCheckBoxes.length; i++){
       setOfCheckBoxes[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(BasicCheckListener);
       }


        get_images.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
**//HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO GET THE VALUES OF THE CHECKBOX BUILD AN ARRAY AND THEN PASS THE ARRAY TO MY FUNCTION.**
                String Image_data = DataCall.getJSON();

                  } 
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(cb1.isChecked())
{

  String url = cb1.getText(); //i assumed you have |x| Text <--- checkbox form
}else if (cb2.isChecked())
{
    String url = cb2.getText();
}
...and so on...
```

But why dont you implement `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` method for each checkbox and whenever any checkbox is checked you get the text from the checkbox by doing only one test `if(checkbox.isChecked()) checkbox.getText()`, instead of doing tons of `ifs`

Comment: Why dont I: because this in only my second app and I'm still a noob. lol but I really like the idea. The user will be able to select multiple check boxes so would I just build an array and keep adding to it every time one is checked? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I put all of my checkboxes in an array and looped through to add an setOnCheckedChangeListenerr.  But not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Dont put them in array. That's a lot of unnecessary memory allocation. You can do as I told you. And don't forget, at time everyone masters in what they are interested. I went through this too. You can use arrays for storing the text from the chkbxes

Implement sOCCListener() for EACH, one-by-one. No arrays, no nothing, the override method might not be called when chkbx is checked.

Comment: You can use array for storing the text from the chkboxes, ofcourse